# Environment variables in route annotations

Tags: php, symfony, routes, annotations, environment-variables

I am making a website that handles subdomains, I have setup an environment variable called base_host and now I want to use this into the `@route` annotation in Symfony 4.

I have tried sofar: `@Route("/", name="homepage", host="{afdeling}.{domain}", defaults={"domain"="%env(base_host)%"}, requirements={"domain"="%env(base_host)%"})` but this give me an error: `using %env(base_host)% is not allowed in routing configuration`

I have also tried: `@Route("/", name="homepage", host="{afdeling}.%env(base_host)%")` this did not work at all.

also what I have tried is: `@Route("/", name="homepage", host="{afdeling}.{domain}", defaults={"domain"="%base_host%"}, requirements={"domain"="%base_host%"})`  but this gives me the error message: `The parameter "base_host" must be defined.`

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Environment variables are not supported (yet) inside routes configuration. As workaround you can create a "*proxy*" container parameter to achieve it:

```
# app/config/config.yml <= Sf 3.4 >= config/services.yaml
parameters:
    base_host: '%env(BASE_HOST)%'
```

Then use `%base_host%` for any route option.

Comment: Still valid today !

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has a significant downside if you are, for instance, building a Docker image and then need to change the value of the BASE_HOST on runtime.

The core of the problem is that the `BASE_HOST` value available at the time you warm up your cache (= most likely when you build your image) will be baked into your pre-compiled routes.

Consequently, if you build the image with `BASE_HOST=example1.com` and then run it in an environment using `BASE_HOST=somethingelse.com`, your application will still include `example1.com` in its routing.

This **will** cause undesired behaviour in redirection, route matching etc.

My current solution is not warming up the cache during the build process, relying on it being built when the container starts in the target environment. The downside of that is that I can no longer run my application on a fully read-only file system.

Answer (score 0):

Full implementation with default value:

```
parameters:
    env(ADMIN_PREFIX_ROUTE): admin
    admin_prefix_route: '%env(ADMIN_PREFIX_ROUTE)%'

admin_controllers:
    prefix: '%admin_prefix_route%'
    resource:
        path: ../src/Admin/Controller/
        namespace: App\Admin\Controller
    type: attribute
```